# how to upload profile picture on xmpp server in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, base64, xmppframework, avatar

```
 filePath = [Imagesdatapath1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",imageName]];
 NSError *errror;
   NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(resizedImage);


 NSXMLElement *vCardXML = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"vCard" xmlns:@"vcard-temp"];
 NSXMLElement *photoXML = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"PHOTO"];
 NSXMLElement *typeXML = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"TYPE" stringValue:@"image/jpg"];


  NSString *strEncoded = [Base64 encode:pngData];

  NSXMLElement *binvalXML = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"BINVAL" stringValue:strEncoded];

 [photoXML addChild:typeXML];
 [photoXML addChild:binvalXML];
 [vCardXML addChild:photoXML];

 XMPPvCardTemp *myvCardTemp = [XMPPvCardTempModule myvCardTemp];

 if (myvCardTemp) {
    [myvCardTemp setPhoto:pngData];
    [ XMPPvCardTempModule updateMyvCardTemp:myvCardTemp];
 }

     [pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:Imagesdatapath1 forKey:@"primagepath"];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

     [self uploadProfileImage:filePath];
```

Please see above code I am working on chat app. I don't know the concept of `xmpp` image upload avatar. I want to upload profile picture (avatar) on `xmpp` server and local database. So, I was import the library like `Base64`, `XMPPvCardTempModule` but till it gives so many library error and what about V card.

Comment: how many library i want to add. please say something step by step so that i can done easily.

Answer (score 1):

1) First, choose the image from Camera or from Gallary And resize it to required form:

```
NSData *img = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(resizedImage)];
```

2) Put your XMPP values as below:

```
            NSXMLElement *vCardXML = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"vCard" xmlns:@"vcard-temp"];
            NSXMLElement *jidElement = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"JABBERID" objectValue:"your_jabberid_here"];
            NSXMLElement *profileUrlElement = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"PROFILEURL" stringValue:"server_file_path_of_image"];
            NSXMLElement *emailElement = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"EMAIL"];
            NSXMLElement *userIdElement = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"USERID" objectValue:"optional_if_you_want_set_email_id"];
            NSXMLElement *userNickname = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"NICKNAME" objectValue:"your_nickName_here"];
```

3) Add Every NSXMLElement tag into vCard as follows:

```
        [emailElement addChild:userIdElement];
        [emailElement addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"INTERNET"]];
        [emailElement addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"PREF"]];
        [vCardXML addChild:jidElement];
        [vCardXML addChild:emailElement];
        [vCardXML addChild:profileUrlElement];
        [vCardXML addChild:userNickname];
```

4) Finally update your vCard as follows:

```
XMPPvCardTemp *newvCardTemp = [XMPPvCardTemp vCardTempFromElement:vCardXML];
            [newvCardTemp setPhoto:img];
            [self->xmppvCardTempModule updateMyvCardTemp:newvCardTemp];
```

You can check Newly set vcard photo by:

```
 XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage *  xmppvCardStorage = [XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
  XMPPvCardTempModule * xmppvCardTempModule = [[XMPPvCardTempModule alloc] initWithvCardStorage:xmppvCardStorage];
    [xmppvCardTempModule  activate:[self xmppStream]];
   XMPPvCardTemp * vcard = [xmppvCardTempModule vCardTempForJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:"your_jid_here" shouldFetch:YES];
    if (vcard.photo) {

        // YOUR_code_goes_here //
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Budhabhooshan, this code helps to save the attachment profile image on local core data with update vcard but once i delete the app and coming back i m not able to get the image as due to its not been uploaded - pls share does your code upload it on server or jsut adding into core data locally ? and how i can upload image on server too ?